# Any Marketing Cloud SDK Resource for Objective - C (Not Swift) Code?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ios, react-native

Currently, I am developing the Marketing Cloud function from React Native using MC SDK, and want to implement push handling Url - Open Direct.

However, documentation to Handling URL using Objective C in Xcode (Not Swift) is already gone and redirected to new documentation

Are there any other docs that I can refer to besides the current one? Because right now codes in the new documentation for iOS are using Swift, and I'm not familiar with that. It's also not the basic language from iOS in React Native.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: We have had Swift documentation for a very long time (ref. https://gist.github.com/sfmc-mobilepushsdk/1b58f9577d22daa4467609263b56d922/revisions).  What part exactly are you struggling with?

Comment: Need help handling open direct URL in Objective C as I mentioned above we are using react-native which used objective c for iOS native code so need documentation or any support code example for handling URL for push notifications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see an old snippet from docs/code here:

```
    // Framework import
#import <MarketingCloudSDK/MarketingCloudSDK.h>

// Make sure your class adopts the protocol
@implementation AppDelegate <MarketingCloudSDKURLHandlingDelegate>

...
// Set the delegate somewhere in your application code (after configuring the SDK)
[[MarketingCloudSDK sharedInstance] sfmc_setURLHandlingDelegate:<set the delegate to 
                                                               be the class implementing 
                                                               the protocol method - example:> self];
...
// EXAMPLE IMPLEMENTATIONS
  
// Implement the protocol method and have iOS handle the URL itself
- (void) sfmc_handleURL:(NSURL *) url type:(NSString *) type
{
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url] == YES) {
        if (@available(iOS 10.0, *)) {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url options:@{} completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
                if (success) {
                  NSLog(@"url %@ opened successfully", url);
                }
                else {
                  NSLog(@"url %@ could not be opened", url);
                }
            }];
        }
        else {
            if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url] == YES) {
                if (url != nil && type != nil) {
                  NSLog(@"url %@ opened successfully", url);
                }
            }
            else
            {
              NSLog(@"url %@ could not be opened", url);
            }
        }
    }
}

// Implement the protocol method and use SFSafariViewController to present the URL within your application
- (void) sfmc_handleURL:(NSURL *) url type:(NSString *) type
{
  UIViewController *topViewController = ... // obtain your app's topmost view controller
  SFSafariViewController *safariViewController = [[SFSafariViewController alloc] initWithURL:url];
  [topController presentViewController:safariViewController animated:YES completion:^{
  }];
}

// Implement the protocol method and take application-specific actions based on the URL itself
- (void) sfmc_handleURL:(NSURL *) url type:(NSString *) type
{
  NSArray *queryItems = url.queryItems;
  for (NSURLQueryItem *item in queryItems) {
    // do something interesting in your application based on the pararmeters in the URL
  }
}
```

ref. https://gist.github.com/sfmc-mobilepushsdk/d9f3ef00c2678aced1d4e19acbc66b02.  If that does not provide enough guidance then I suggest you seek professional implementation assistance.

Comment: This helped me a lot thank you so much

Comment: @Bill Mote, I have applied same in my `React Native` Mobile app with `react-native-marketingcloudsdk`, it's not working as expected, I mean push notification with `OpenDirect` not opening the URL in browser. I have done this implementation `// Implement the protocol method and have iOS handle the URL itself`

Comment: ```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application sfmc_handleURL:(NSURL *) url type:(NSString *) type
{
    NSLog(@"sfmc_handleURL > type: %@", type);
    NSLog(@"sfmc_handleURL > url: %@", url);

    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url] == YES) {
      [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url options:@{} completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {}];
    }
}
```